# Is it possible to convert (Date Time) to (SmallDatetime, not null) (01 MMM yyyy)?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to convert (Date Time) to (SmallDatetime, not null) (01 MMM yyyy)?

Convert 2022-12-31 00:00:00.000 to 31 DEC 2022, I have tried CAST(T0.RefDate as smalldatetime) and comes out as 2023-12-31 00:00:00.

Comment: What is your purpose in the first place? What is the difference between 2022-12-31 00:00:00.000, 31 DEC 2022 or 2022-12-31 00:00:00? All of them are pointing to same datetime, no?

Comment: Dates don't have formats. When you try to print the date it will have a time component. Or you can use `CONVERT(varchar(30), ...` with a style number. If you want to actually store it as just a date, why not use the `DATE` data type?

Comment: To be honest, this is a client requirement and they are stating they want date as (SmallDatetime, not null) (01 MMM yyyy). Which does not make sense to me, but they insist.

Comment: *All* date and time data types can be converted from one to the other, both implicitly and explicitly, without error. The only exceptions would be where you are converting a value which falls outside of the date ranges for `smalldatetime` (prior to 1900-01-01 or after 2079-06-06T23:59) or `datetime` (before 1753-01-01).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not casting but formatting a datetime value for display. ie:

```
select FORMAT(T0.RefDate,'dd MMM yyyy') as displayVal from myTable;
```

Comment: To be honest, this is a client requirement and they are stating they want date as (SmallDatetime, not null) (01 MMM yyyy). Which does not make sense to me, but they insist.

Comment: @TichaonaJermaineGaza No it doesn't make sense at all, that's just not how SQL works. Either you want `smalldatetime` or you want a string.

Comment: @TichaonaJermaineGaza, sorry I don't understand what you mean saying smalldatetime. I can't see what outcome you would have. It would still be the same value (internally still a number). What you are after is actually string format as I believe. You can achieve it using Format() or Convert() with style.

Comment: Thank you Charlie and @Cetin for your input. I'm in total agreement with you, just needed confirmation or to find out if there's any 'trick' I can use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to just format it into a string for display, rather than convert to a binary `smalldatetime` value.

You can use the [`CONVERT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with a style

```sql
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar(30), T0.RefDate, 106)
FROM YourTable;
```